# gulp watch on change wait for task to complete before executing on change

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have a watch occurring for my scss files which functions great. When a change is made, the task is running.

```
var sassWatch = gulp.watch([paths.root + '**/*.scss'], ['sass']);
```

Now, when a change is detected, I want to take the file that was changed, change the extension to .css and then do something with said css file.

```
sassWatch.on('change', function (ev) {
        changeNotification('Sass file', ev.type, 'Running compilation');
        ev.path = ev.path.substr(0, ev.path.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".css";
        return gulp.src(ev.path).pipe(slang(ev.path)); // DO SOMETHING WITH CSS FILE
    });
```

The problem is that the last line of the on('change'... runs before the sass task is completed.

```
[11:30:46] Sass file was changed. Running compilation & slinging to AEM.
[11:30:46] Starting 'sass'...
[11:30:46] Starting 'sass:compile'...
[11:30:46] DO SOMETHING WITH CSS FILE
[11:30:50] Finished 'sass:compile' after 4.59 s
[11:30:50] Starting 'css:clean'...
[11:30:50] Finished 'css:clean' after 3.45 ms
[11:30:50] Finished 'sass' after 4.6 s
```

Is there a way to prevent some or all of the on change function from executing before the task has been completed? My ideal scenario would be as follows:

```
[11:30:46] Sass file was changed. Running compilation & slinging to AEM.
[11:30:46] Starting 'sass'...
[11:30:46] Starting 'sass:compile'...
[11:30:46] Finished 'sass:compile' after 4.59 s
[11:30:50] Starting 'css:clean'...
[11:30:50] Finished 'css:clean' after 3.45 ms
[11:30:50] Finished 'sass' after 4.6 s
[11:30:50] DO SOMETHING WITH CSS FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`run-sequence`](http://npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) package let's you run multiple tasks one after the other. In your case you don't actually need to run multiple tasks. You just need to run one task and then execute a function.

Luckily `run-sequence` accepts a callback function that is called when all the tasks have finished running. So you really just need to stick the whole `DO SOMETHING WITH CSS FILE` thing in that callback function:

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.watch([paths.root + '**/*.scss'], function (ev) {
  runSequence('sass', function() {
    changeNotification('Sass file', ev.type, 'Running compilation');
    ev.path = ev.path.substr(0, ev.path.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".css";
    return gulp.src  (ev.path).pipe(slang(ev.path)); // DO SOMETHING WITH CSS FILE
  });
});
```